# How to know you're at the last pass of a for loop through object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object like so:

```
var obj = { thing_1 : false,
            thing_2 : false,
            thing_3 : true,
            thing_4 : false,
            thing_5 : true
           }
```

I am now looping through this object and searching for the object keys that are true, like so:

```
  for (value in obj){  
    if (obj[value] === true ){
      // do something
    }
  }
```

How do I know when I have reached the last loop pass where one of the keys is true?

Comment: Why do you want to know, any specific reason for that

Comment: @VivekGupta Popular use case: string concatenation, but not appending to the last value

Comment: @VivekGupta The reason is I am doing an asynchronous call on every loop pass, and so I want to know when the last asynchronous call is actually completed.

Comment: @Squrler That is an *entirely* different question. This will not tell you when the last async call will finish

Comment: I know that. I didn't ask that question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *`count`* the `object` elements with `Object.keys(obj).length`, and then checks inside the loop to find when you're working with the last one.

> *The [Object.keys(obj)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).*

Example:

```
var obj = {
  thing_1: false,
  thing_2: false,
  thing_3: true,
  thing_4: false,
  thing_5: true
};

var count = 0;
for (var value in obj) {

  count++;

  if (count == Object.keys(obj).length) {
    console.log('And the last one is:');
  }

  console.log(obj[value]);

}
```

**Note:** As you can imagine, this has some problems with `IE < 9`...
you could make your own custom function or go ahead with `polifill`...
Read more about this [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object-that-is-associative-array).